# How much is the resource limit in a qml.qrc file for Android?

Tags: android, qt, video, qml, resources

Hello I want to add in my Android app some videos and image. I tried to put inside a video and it was more or less 15 mb to try.
So i searched to put inside more images and it rejected them saying that the size was too much.
So if i have this qrc.qml file

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>main.qml</file>
     .....
    <file>video1.mp4</file>
    <file>video2.mp4</file>
    <file>video3.mp4</file>
    <file>video4.mp4</file>
    .....
    <file>image1.jpg</file>
    <file>image2.jpg</file>
    <file>image3.jpg</file>
    <file>image4.jpg</file>        
    .....
</qresource>
```

What's the limit? or There is another way to put inside more files in the app?

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual error message that you're seeing. Is it from the C++ compiler or from rcc? Have you tried breaking up your qrc into multiple qrc files?

Answer (score 1):

What build system are you using. If using cmake I would recommend to have a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-cmake-qt5-add-big-resources.html